# how to create variable and do something just in one line

Tags: python

How to create a variable in just one line without using
`;` and the `exec` function and do things on that variable

again just in one line

for example

```
input_string = str(input())
array = []
for i in range(len(input_string)):
    if (ord(input_string[i]) - 97) % 2 == 0:
        array.append(input_string[i])
    else:
        array.append(input_string[i].upper())
array.sort(reverse=True)
answer = ' '.join(array)
print(answer)
```

**Solution that i did**

```
input_string = str(input());print(' '.join(reversed(sorted([input_string[i] if ((ord(input_string[i]) - 97) % 2 == 0) else input_string[i].upper() for i in range(len(input_string))]))))
```

*but if you are careful*

I used `;` right after assigning the variable. But I do not want to !!

can i do that without using `;` or not?

Comment: Why do you need it all on one line? Having it on more lines make it less confusing and more 'pythonic'.

Comment: Why don't you switch to java and code your whole program in one line? I am sure that way it is much better!

Comment: Walrus operator (`:=`) does not work inside list comprehensions so the answer is NO, you can not do what you want in just one line. Also I agree with everyone saying that it wouldn't be a good idea even if you could

Comment: @MatteoZanoni Walrus does work in list comps, what are you talking about?

Comment: @KellyBundy not really... if you try to run `(a[i] for i in range(len(a:=input())))` you will get a SyntaxError (at least in python3.9)

Comment: The crux of this is that OP only needs `input_string` in the body of the loop because they're unnecessarily iterating over its indices; the entire problem goes away if they just do `for s in input()` instead.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni Ok, that particular way doesn't work. You can use walrus in other places in a list comp, though.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's more to your program where you need the value of `input_string` (in which case why are you trying to put this specific piece on one line?), you can easily avoid the problem by not assigning it to a variable in the first place and just using the return value of `input()` directly in the spot where it's needed.

```
>>> print(*(sorted((s if ord(s) % 2 else s.upper() for s in input()), reverse=True)))
abcdefg
g e c a F D B
```

Note that your original code includes a lot of expressions that can be simplified and/or made more "Pythonic"; for example:

```
str(input())
```

should just be:

```
input()
```

and:

```
for i in range(len(input_string)):
    ...input_string[i]...
```

should be:

```
for s in input_string:
    ...s...  # now you don't need input_string inside the loop!
```

or similar, and you can take advantage of "truthiness" (and the fact that subtracting an odd number will always exactly reverse its value modulo 2) to turn this:

```
    if (ord(s) - 97) % 2 == 0:
        array.append(s)
    else:
        array.append(s.upper())
```

into the much more concise:

```
    if ord(s) % 2:
        array.append(s)
    else:
        array.append(s.upper())
```

and then of course the entire loop can be compacted down by turning it into a generator expression, as you already figured out.

Comment: ah, good point!

Comment: It does change the parity, though :-)

Comment: thank you. i didn't know about that we can pass input in the expression

Answer (score -2):

It seems there is no way. based on ([Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html)) article, you have to use indentation or semicolon. It's not a good practice but still if you insist to use something else, you can define a special symbol and before running the code, replace that symbol to `semicolon ;` again.